# Internet Radio Device with batteries

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, raspberry-pi, ethernet, decoder

I have an project that I will make connection with Internet and listen a stream(in my case *IP:port online radio station*) then decode the music and transmit it to speakers connected to the microcontroller.

At first, I thought that Ardiuno UNO can be used with ethernet shield and mp3 decoder shield. But, AFAI research, two shields cannot be used on it. Furthermore, a comment  that

> Not a chance. Even the ESP8266, which has many times the RAM and
>   processing power of an UNO requires an external RAM chip for
>   buffering. The UNO will never be able to decode the audio fast enough,
>   and it doesn't have an analog output to drive the speaker. I'd
>   recommend using a Raspberry Pi or similar. This is not a task for a
>   microcontroller.

Secondly, I thought that Raspberry Pi could be used but I heard it doesn't work with battery cell.

Morever, we need a microcontroller working with battery cells and meets the expectations to build the project.

There are some similar links related to the project,

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=85191.0
https://www.jaycollett.com/2011/07/retro-wifi-radio/
https://cassiopeia.hk/internetradio/

Youtube in action,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCott53kQvI

What do you propose to me for the project to be achieved? How can I overcome the project?

### @Edit

What about **raspberry pi zero??**

Comment: https://cassiopeia.hk/internetradio/

Comment: A Raspberry Pi can be operated on a battery.  A larger battery than for an Arduino, but it can be done.

Comment: @JRE - no, a pi is really not realistic for battery operation.  Battery powered systems need to be designed for that from the ground up, and the pi is based on a chip intended to be a mains powered TV set top box.  It is fundamentally unsuitable.

Comment: @ChrisStratton:  The "UPS" boards for Pi argue otherwise.

Comment: @JRE - a UPS is implicitly a short-duration device.  You can run a desktop PC briefly that way too, but it doesn't mean you can meaningfully use it on batteries.  In contrast, a system actually designed for battery power can scale its consumption quickly to match actual need, and can suspend to a low power state without having to do an operating system shutdown and new boot.  Compare for example power management in phone hardware and operating systems.  The pi is missing all that, because it was not a design goal for the chip.

Comment: @ChrisStratton so what is your advice for me?

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname preferably pick a better project, or change the design parameters to allow mains power.  IP networking and batteries are a difficult combination, requiring care to all parts of the engineering including those which you as a single individual can't readily get your hands into.

Comment: @ChrisStratton If we change the power option to electrical power, what would you offer? Rasperry pi ?? with modules or something else?? What about raspberry pi zero??

Comment: Preferably a router chip booting from SPI flash and running in RAM as these are more robust for an actual *product* and so unsurprisingly are what get used in such products.  For a student demonstration you can use a pi, but you'll need to remember to do an orderly shut it down before removing power.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thank you indeed. Yes, we've decided to use raspberry pi zero w, which can also be powered by more than 3.3V -  less than 6V LiOn battery. pi will simplify the task IMHO very much.

Comment: No.  Powering a pi directly from a lithium ion battery is not a workable idea.  At best it will work for a while then fail erratically, possibly at the worst possible time in terms of file system survival.

Comment: @ChrisStratton But sir, I have read https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/smallest-battery-that-can-run-the-raspberry-pi-zero-w-for-a-short-amount-of-time and https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=194048, it seems ok. ???

Comment: @ChrisStratton what about LiPo ??

Comment: Raspberry pi stack exchange is notoriously inaccurate - it's part of the problem with that being its own small site of fans walled off from actual engineering understanding.  Your second link includes some of the discussion of discharge curves illustrating why this is a bad idea.

Comment: @ChrisStratton **as a final word**, how can I supply battery power to raspberry pi zero w? Must I use only electrical power??

Comment: We already talked about that - battery power is practically unsuitable for this project and most projects requiring ongoing IP networking.  And using a pi which requires orderly shutdown only adds to the short life issue a potential need to re-generate the card image one.

Answer (score 1):

> At first, I thought that Ardiuno UNO can be used with ethernet shield and mp3 decoder shield. But, AFAI research, two shields cannot be used on it.

Depends on the shields and what pins they use. They have stacking headers on them for a reason, after all!

The real obstacle, however, is decoding the MP3 on the microcontroller. This is flat-out impossible on an Arduino: a single MP3 frame decodes to 1152 samples, which would almost completely fill the 2KB of RAM on an ATmega328P, leaving no room for temporary memory in the decoder, or for buffers used by the TCP stack.

> Secondly, I thought that Raspberry Pi could be used but I heard it doesn't work with battery cell.

That is incorrect. Most Raspberry Pi models draw a maximum of ~500 mA while running -- down to 100 mA for some models -- which is well within the capacity of even a small battery. (Even a cell phone power bank would likely suffice.)

A Raspberry Pi is probably overkill for this project, though. You don't need a whole Linux OS just to play audio, and the availability of audio players for Linux would sort of trivialize this project anyway. Consider using an ARM microcontroller with Ethernet support; for instance, ST has a couple of Discovery development kits which would be perfect for this. (For instance, the 32F746GDISCOVERY has an Ethernet PHY and an audio codec on board.)

Comment: Your Arduino analysis misses the actual point - the reason an Arduino can't be used with the mentioned *hardware decoding* mp3 shield is the lack of buffer memory to deal with network burstiness.  You'll have largely the same problem with a flash-based ARM MCU which also has moderately limited RAM until you get to high price points.  In practice network streaming audio players typically aren't battery powered, but are mains powered things based on router chips running Linux.  If you want to make a battery powered one, you're basically looking for a trailing edge phone.

Comment: @duskwuff what about raspberry pi zero??

Comment: What about it. Explain why you think this might work. (Give your power requirement calculations.)